# Dealing with vscode setting workspace python.pythonPath in git tracked project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are working in a team and are tracking out .vscode folder including the settings.json. When I change my conda environment it adds the following line to my settings

```
"python.pythonPath": "/home/sev/anaconda3/envs/testenv/bin/python",
```

Tracking this parameter would create problems in 2 ways for us:

1. The path is pointing to a folder which does not exist in my teammates machines
2. As my teammates are working on different parts of the project, they want to load a different enviroment other than testenv by default

When working without the `.vscode` folder this is not a problem as the user settings are used. Is it possible to make vscode use the user settings for this particular setting and not add it everytime we change environment?

I found the following github issue relating to this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2125 but there seems to be no solution (that I am able to understand) yet. Is the way to go just to not share workspace settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opting in to the following AB experiment solved my problem
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments